# How to Rewrite URL in web.config file to hide index.php in url like http://demo.example.com/dir/dir/index.php/login?

Tags: php, asp.net, laravel-5, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a Laravel app hosted on a .net panel, which works fine if installed in the root. But I have to use it inside of two sub-directories after root, i.e. it's installed in root/dir1/dir2/app. Now below is my current code in the web.config file which works fine if the app is installed directly in the root directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Move to index.php">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
         <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So, currently, http://demo.example.com/dir1/dir2/index.php/login works, but I need it to be like http://demo.example.com/dir1/dir2/login , is it possible? If so, please explain your answer as much as possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I figured it out. Actually, my parent directory's web.config was conflicting with the sub-dir web.config file, so I added `<clear />` after the `<rules>` tag in both of them and now it's working fine. Check out the below final code that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Move to index.php">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
         <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this might help someone else too.

Comment: Thanks for this.
has this worked for IIS windows hosting with Plesk server for laravel?